# Apache2 сменить DocumentRoot

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, lamp

Здравствуйте!

Сменил хостера, и теперь приходится все заного настраивать (до этого хостер настраивал все).

Установил Lamp, ubuntu 16.04, php 7

**Вопрос в том**, как настроить апач так, что бы он был направлен на `/home/user/$sitename`, а уже в `$sitename` лежал файл настроек апача для определенного сайта.

До этого (на старом хостере) именно так работало.

Гуглил, ничего толком не нагуглил.

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: `Include /home/user/*/*.conf`?

Comment: Получается в 000-default.conf стереть все, прописать только подключение файла, и будит работать?

Comment: У вас главный файл Apache - 000-default.conf? Не httpd.conf? В главном конфиге пишите то, что относится ко всему серверу. Частные вещи, различные для разных виртуальных хостов - в подключаемых.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо) а главный httpd.conf